# VS Code how to debug ruby on rails and react at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I know how to debug ruby on rails and react(by `Debugger for Chrome`) in vs code separately.

If I put react in a rails folder named `frontend`. Can I use vs code to start them and debug them at the same time?

Currently, I am rely on `Chrome` to debug frontend. Any chance for me to use  `Debugger for Chrome`, so that I can set break point in vs code for react code?